# How to enable verbose logging in ChromeDriver? (GebConfig)

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have to enable verbose logging in Chrome / ChromeDriver to see why my geb tests are failing. Does anybody know how I can do that. Heres my GebConfig:

```
String chromeDriverDownloadFullPath = "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/${chromeDriverVersion}/${chromeDriverZipFileName}"
File chromeDriverLocalFile = downloadDriver(
        currentPlatformName,
        chromeDriverDownloadFullPath,
        chromeDriverExecFileName,
        'zip',
        "chrome",
        chromeDriverVersion)

System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver', chromeDriverLocalFile.absolutePath)

Locale locale = getLocale()
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--lang=" + locale.country);
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=/data");


DesiredCapabilities jsCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome()
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>()
prefs.put("intl.accept_languages", locale.toLanguageTag())
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs)
jsCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options)

ChromeDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options)
chromeDriver.manage().window().setSize(getDimension())
return chromeDriver
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To obtain verbose logs from **`ChromeDriver`** we can configure the **`logfile`** and the **`type_of_logging`** as follows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.log");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true");
```

### Update :

I can see from your code you have provided :

```
System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver', chromeDriverLocalFile.absolutePath)
```

In a similar fashion try to provide :

```
System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.logfile', chromeDriverLocalFile.absolutePath);
System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging', boolean);
```

Comment: Can I set the logfile Path e.g. "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.log" to any other Path?

Comment: @adbo Yeah you can.

Comment: I am getting the following error: Failed to redirect stderr to log file.
    Unable to initialize logging. Exiting...

Comment: I can see from your code you have provided : 

 System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver', chromeDriverLocalFile.absolutePath) 
 
In a similar fashion try to provide :

 System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.logfile', chromeDriverLocalFile.absolutePath);
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true");

Comment: And where is the logfile going (Where can I find it later?). Perhaps these are stupid questions - sorry.

Comment: At the same place which you are referring as `chromeDriverLocalFile.absolutePath`. Else create a separate location by referencing it as **`chromeDriverLocalFile.absoluteLOGPath`** and pass the **`constant`** within **`System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.logfile', chromeDriverLocalFile.absoluteLOGPath);`**

Comment: Still getting these error. I am running the Tests with Jenkins in a Docker-Container  - Perhaps it is a PermissionProblem. But for now - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation of ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging)

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "Your path");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true");
```